# Upgrading a running Tomcat servlet

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, web-deployment

I have a Tomcat server (in a VPS hosting) which contains some servlets and JSP files (obviously).

The question is... when I make some updating (fixing code, bugfixes, etc.) to a servlet code or a JSP file in my localhost, **how should I proceed to deploy the changes in the remote server**?

I guess I should replace the original JSP by the newer one (isn't it? or should I have to do more stuff?). But what I don't know is how to proceed with the servlet changes.

I know that if I re-upload the whole war, restart tomcat service it will work, but maybe there's an easier way to do what I need.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the JSPs, you need to replace the Servlet classes in the deployed webapp. To get them working, there is no way than to restart the web application (or the whole Tomcat, but there is no need for that unless you use native libs).

So uploading the war file (with Tomcats hot deploy activated) is the one and only way to do it. Tomcat will stop the application, deploy the new war, and restart the application.

That's as easy as it can be.

Comment: So the solution is upload again the war file for any change on JSP or an individual Servlet, isn't it? Wow... my war could be some hundreds of MB